# All downloads from iframe go to folder in server

Tags: javascript, php, html

My website contains a iframe which allows the user to navigate the web. If the user clicks a download button on any website I would like it to download in a folder located on the servers itself. So if the user presses download on a image, the image is downloaded onto a folder on the server instead of the computer. Is this possible? I have no idea on how to go about doing this.

Comment: You are not doing "download" you need a button that will trigger a file copy in the server. Check how to copy files in the server language you're using, and from there, just create some kind of URL that triggers such action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to need to display a download button on any website...

You cannot modify all internet websites with your code.
The only way to go this is :

- to create a browser extension, like this one : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/image-downloader/cnpniohnfphhjihaiiggeabnkjhpaldj

This extension will be able to interact with any website and do what you want.

- or (more simple to code) execute a Javascript of your own that will make floating a download button on any image of any website.
  You can do this with this Chrome extension for example : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/custom-javascript-for-web/poakhlngfciodnhlhhgnaaelnpjljija

You can also use a "download" button over the iframe that launch a `curl` Linux command that will download the iframe page and all the images, files etc...